# Using awk to find pattern pair and join lines

Tags: awk

I have a huge file with some process´s log.
The log have lines like "REQUEST (always)/RESPONSE (sometimes)" but RESPONSE is not necessarily the next line after REQUEST. The REQUEST header may occur several times before a RESPONSE if it occurs.
I would like to join the REQUEST and RESPONSE (if exists) and then print the line.
This is what I tried so far but the output is missing some lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN {filename = "log1.etb"}
    {line_num++; print "FNR: " FNR " NR: " NR " Counter: " line_num;
    if ($0 ~ /REQUEST.*RPCLIB/)
                        {seqid = $0; sub(/^.*@SeqID/,"SeqID",seqid);
                        line_req = $0; line_resp = ""; ref_resp = 0;
                        ref_req = line_num; tot_req++;
                        print "REQUEST: " $0;
                        for(i=1;i<=line_num+99999;i++1) {getline < "log.etb"; if ($0 ~ /RESPONSE/ && $0 ~ seqid) {ref_resp = +i; line_resp = $0; break;}};
                        print "FNR: " FNR " NR: " NR " REQUEST: " ref_req " RESPONSE: " ref_resp " " seqid;
                        print line_req"+"line_resp > filename;
                        FNR = line_num-1; NR = FNR;
                        }
    }
    END {print "Total REQUEST: " tot_req}
    ' ../EXX/log.etb
```

Input:

```
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517
RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517 , Partner SeqID = 3393
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9515
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520
RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520 , Partner SeqID = 3395
```

Desired output:

```
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517+W02/RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517 , Partner SeqID = 3393
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9515+
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520+W02/RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520 , Partner SeqID = 3395
```

SeqID number connects the REQUEST/RESPONSE but it may reoccur in log at some point.
Also REQUESTs can occur many times before a RESPONSE and RESPONSE may or may not occur.

Comment: It's not explicit in the question, but from tho code I think I can make out that it's the number after `SeqID =` that connects a request with a response. Is that correct? Could you maybe mention that in the question?

Comment: That's correct but in some point the SeqID may repeat that's why I put a counter to search the next 99999 lines after the REQUEST header.

Comment: KIndly post input and expected output

Comment: Edited the post to insert new info. Thanks @PraveenKumarBS

Comment: Does the `Unique-ID` uniquely identify a request and it's associated response ?

Comment: @MarceloMiranda I’m no awk expert but to me it seems that your code needs at least to do `close("data");` at the end of the for loop, otherwise the `getline < "data"` command will only work for the first loop. Also, you search for REQUEST.*RPCLIB but I don't see any RPCLIB string in your example input.

Comment: I’m sorry for you if your real data has lines that are longer than 450 characters long, but please post ***example*** data that doesn’t require horizontal scrolling (i.e., about 80 characters per line). And keep example numbers to two digits (i.e., less than 100).

Comment: @iruvar unfortunatelly Unique-ID does not identify uniquely a resquest/response. It only works for request that were satisfied not necessarily with response.

Comment: @LL3 good call. I'll try with "close (data)". My example input isn't correct because there are REQUESTs with and without RPCLIB in it.

Comment: @G-Man I'll try to put and example a little more accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with below method and it worked fine

```
for i in `cat k.txt| awk  -F "=" '{print $2}'| awk -F "," '{print $1}'| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sort| uniq`; do sed -n '/'$i'/p' k.txt|sed '1s/$/\+/g'| sed "N;s/\n/W02\//g";done
```

output

```
for i in `cat k.txt| awk  -F "=" '{print $2}'| awk -F "," '{print $1}'| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sort| uniq`; do sed -n '/'$i'/p' k.txt|sed '1s/$/\+/g'| sed "N;s/\n/W02\//g";done

REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9515+
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517+W02/RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.809@{fields}@SeqID     = 9517 , Partner SeqID = 3393
REQUEST  2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520+W02/RESPONSE 2019-01-16 00:32:07.810@{fields}@SeqID     = 9520 , Partner SeqID = 3395
praveen@praveen:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so i post my comment as answer, sorry for that.
You want to join REQUEST and RESPONSE if their seqid matches, right?
Why not sort your data by seqid first? It will make sure RESPONSE always follow it's REQUEST.

Comment: I tried that but in some point the seqid repeats also if I put in date+time order the next line could not be the RESPONSE, could be another REQUEST.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with `awk` but I made this Bash script that does the thing.

**It requires at least Bash v4**, but that should be quite widespread..

It expects input from stdin, meaning that you need to invoke it as in:

```
cat logfile | script.sh
```

or also:

```
script.sh < logfile
```

I did so on purpose thinking that it might be desirable, but it's easy to embed the filename within the script by just e.g. adding it to the `cat -n` command, before the `|`.

It handles:

- missing responses
- duplicate requests, joining the response to the latest request found with that id
- takes SeqID fields following the @-sign (*see the regex in the first `sed` command*)
- uses REQUEST and RESPONSE literal regexs as criteria for record distinction (*see the `if-elif-else-fi` code block*)
- joins matching req/resp pairs with `+`

HTH

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A reqs=()

{
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    read -r seqid rest <<<"${line}"
    line="${line#${seqid} }"
    if [[ "${line}" =~ REQUEST ]] ; then
        [ "${reqs[$seqid]}" ] && printf '%s+\n' "${reqs[$seqid]}"
        reqs[$seqid]="${line}"
    elif [[ "${line}" =~ RESPONSE ]] && [ "${reqs[$seqid]}" ] ; then
        printf '%s+%s\n' "${reqs[$seqid]}" "${line}"
        unset reqs[$seqid]
    else
        printf 'strange record at line no. %s\n' "${line}" >&2
    fi
done < <(cat -n | sed -e 's/\(.*@\)SeqID *= *\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/\2 &/') ;
printf '%s+\n' "${reqs[@]}" ;
} | sort -k 1 | sed -e 's/\(^\|+\)[[:blank:]]\+[0-9]\+[[:blank:]]\+/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code but it takes too long on huge file:

```
awk '{
    if ($0 ~ /REQUEST/ && $0 ~ /RPCLIB/)
        {seqid = $0; sub(/^.*@SeqID/,"SeqID",seqid);
        line_req = $0; line_resp = "";
        rng_s = NR; rng_e = NR + 99999;
        cmd = "awk '\''/RESPONSE.*" seqid "/ && NR >= " rng_s " && NR <= " rng_e " {print $0;exit}'\'' logfile"
        cmd | getline line_resp;
        close(cmd);
        print line_req"+"line_resp;
        }
    }
    ' logfile
```